# WPF Application has WndProc Exception in Windows 10; Not seen in Windows 8, 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, wndproc, windows-10

It is my hope that there are developers out there who have undertaken to start work in Windows 10.  I have not immersed myself to the point where I am coding strictly in Windows 10.  Hopefully there are those of you out there who have seen similar behavior as explained below.

This application is a proprietary design; I won't be able to give too many details of a finer nature.  I can tell you that it deals with getting the location of UI Automation Elements within any window on a screen.

This WPF application works very well in Windows 8 and 8.1.
It works well in Windows 10, too.  But I am getting the exception below when I attempt to use the application in the "Metro Outlook Mail" app.
In general, WndProc in this class is dealing with the detection of pen events and finger events.

**Here is the exception detail:**

```
WndProc Exception: 
The pipe is being closed. 
Failed to get raw data from the pointer device. 
at WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
```

Please let me know if any of you have seen this when testing your pre-Windows 10 app on a Windows 10 system.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the version of Windows 10 I was testing was too green.  In testing the next release, this error went away.